# I can't build angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

when i try to build angular project with command ng build --prod
i faced below error
**An unhandled exception occurred: Transform failed with 1 error:
error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"**

**[error] HookWebpackError: Transform failed with 1 error:
error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"
at makeWebpackError (\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:48:9)
at \node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3055:12
at eval (eval at create (\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :98:1)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
-- inner error --
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"
at failureErrorWithLog (\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1557:15)
at \node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1346:29
at \node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:637:9
at handleIncomingPacket (\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:734:9)
at Socket.readFromStdout (\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:604:7)
at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)**

Comment: try to uninstall angular completely and install it again

Comment: i solve the issue after added below in .browserslistrc file                                               
not ios_saf 15.2-15.3
not safari 15.2-15.3

Answer (score 1):

I solve the issue after added below in .browserslistrc file
**not ios_saf 15.2-15.3
not safari 15.2-15.3**